# Running Turtlebot Navigation Stack on multiple floors

Tags: gazebo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I currently have a Gazebo world that I generated with two levels. Level 9 (z=0) and Level 10 (z= 20).
[image: image description]
[image: image description]

When I am using the navigation stack on level 9, the local costmap and global costmap is being generated. It is able to navigate successfully.

However, when I move to level 10, the local costmap is not being generated and the robot relies purely on the global costmap to avoid obstacles. Is there a way to fix this. I am using the turtlebot simulation stack found on github. Would appreciate any pointers as I have started playing with the local cost params but that does not seem to be affecting anything.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/381957/running-turtlebot-navigation-stack-on-multiple-floors/) by [kidRobot](https://answers.ros.org/users/66568/kidrobot/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2021-07-07

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2021-07-07**:
Possible partial/whole duplicate of https://answers.ros.org/question/246854/multi-floor-navigation/

**Comment by [kidRobot](https://answers.ros.org/users/66568/kidrobot/) on 2021-07-08**:
Unfortunately those implementations don't seem to work right now and don't solve my problem. My problem is specifically with the local costmap not updating on floors that are not set at z=0 in gazebo

**Comment by [prince](https://answers.ros.org/users/939/prince/) on 2021-07-08**:
Which package are you currently running for transistions between floors/level specific navigation?

**Comment by [Mike Scheutzow](https://answers.ros.org/users/75154/mike-scheutzow/) on 2021-07-09**:
Do you need this to work for real physical robots, or is this simulation-only?

**Comment by [Mike Scheutzow](https://answers.ros.org/users/75154/mike-scheutzow/) on 2021-07-09**:
Please edit your question and append your config for the local costmap. Use the 101010 button to format yaml text.

**Comment by [Mike Scheutzow](https://answers.ros.org/users/75154/mike-scheutzow/) on 2021-07-16**:
Have you figured out how to get this to work?

**Comment by [kidRobot](https://answers.ros.org/users/66568/kidrobot/) on 2021-08-13**:
Just managed to get it to work, have added the answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, So I think I have found the solution, although it seems to be a patch more than an actual solution. As I said before, if the z-coordinate of the robot was 0, there was no problem, but when the robot went to a certain level, the scans were not returning anything despite obstacles being present.

The patch was essentially to add a "tf_fixer" where I set the z-coordinate of the robot to always be zero, regardless of the level it was on. That seemed to have fixed the problem, will continue to edit this answer if I come across a better solution.

---

Originally posted by [kidRobot](https://answers.ros.org/users/66568/kidrobot/) with karma: 21 on 2021-08-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There is a reason that the move_base navigation stack is called "2.5D" and not "3D": much of the code **assumes** that the robot's position is uniquely defined by (x, y, theta). It has no concept of "z". For some scenarios, you can fake it: either 1) put both levels on a single "flat" map (so x,y coord is unique), OR 2) load a new map  & costmap if the robot switches "level".

---

Originally posted by [Mike Scheutzow](https://answers.ros.org/users/75154/mike-scheutzow/) with karma: 4903 on 2021-07-07

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kidRobot](https://answers.ros.org/users/66568/kidrobot/) on 2021-07-07**:
Hi, but even after loading a new map everytime it switches floors, the global costmap is able to update itself but the local costmap is not

**Comment by [prince](https://answers.ros.org/users/939/prince/) on 2021-07-08**:
You will need to move the robot to different floor in gazebo for update of the costmap. Please check whether the sensor data is being published in correct frames.